# How to Pass data from Grand Child to Parent component and append the updated state to Child Component in Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Need to update the state value in Parent component from Grand Child Component. My component tree structure goes like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3r3.png)

I have the state value available in LeftFilter componenet (Grand Child Component). Need to pass to UserList (Parent Component ) and in change handler filter the value and  update the state then append the updated state value to  DataGrid Component ( Child Component inside UserList Component)

My parent component goes like this :-

```
function UserList() {
/***/
return (
<>
<DataGrid>
</>
```

Child Component

```
function DataGrid() {
/***/
return (
<>
<FilterModal>
</>
```

Grand Child

```
function FilterModal() {
/***/
return (
<>
<LeftFilter>
</>
```

I have a state value in LeftFilter, with that state I need to pass it to UserList and in change handler need to perform a filter operation with array of objects and append the state value. That updated state value will be append to